# Nodejs https request UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

OS: debian sid

Nodejs: v0.10.38

I have a request to a private service that use authentication:

```js
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    host: 'private.service.com',
    path: '/accounts/' + '123323' + '/orders',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'asdsdgcvxcvxcv'
    }
};

var request = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

When i run the script, node throws this error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1381:32)
    at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:980:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:472:13)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:369:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24)
```

The same exact script worked well for months, and i'm sure the authentication is correct. Today is the first time i have this situation.

**Which can be the cause for this error?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a reason for SSL. Besides other features, it authenticates that you are really communicating with the server identified by `private.service.com` hostname. Otherwise your client software can be cheated by a Man-in-the-Middle attack.

First when anyone encounters this issue, they should update system root SSL certificates. In Debian they are contained in `ca-certificates` apt-get package.

If it doesn't help, the server probably uses an issuer certificate, which is not trusted by default worldwide PKI infrastructure. In this case the client should compare the certificate public key signature with a preshared value. This is known as "certificate pinning".

Specifically to your error, if it worked before, it is possible that the server certificate has expired. The server should renew it. As a temporary solution, you can turn off PKI validation by `rejectUnauthorized` option. However you should use it together with the pinning approach. In NodeJS, you can get the server certificate fingerprint from `res.socket.getPeerCertificate().fingerprint`.

Comment: I'm going to try your suggestion, i'll let you know, thanks for the deeper explanation.

Answer (score 17):

After some study i found that this is a problem of the server that i'm trying to make the https request to.

Node https cannot find the ssl ISSUER_CERT on the private.service server and so it throw that exception.

The solution i used, since i'm sure i can trust that server, was to add

```
            rejectUnauthorized: false
```

to the options of the https request, this way node will not throw an exception in case of certificates problem.

Anyway this solution is valid only if you know you can trust the host of your request, otherwise it's probably not the best solution.

Comment: See my answer why while this is enough to "get it working", it endangers your client app to MitM attacks.

Comment: Thanks for rejectUnauthorized: false. it worked. even though zakjan mentioned it in his answer, you have mentioned where it has to be added.

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS**. You are using SSL for security and then explicitly turning it off, so then why bother with SSL in the first place? You are opening yourself up to man in the middle attacks since your client can no longer be sure of the identity of the server.

Comment: It could be OK to disable this in testing or non-prod environments.

Answer (score 4):

After a reasearch this solved the problem:

```
npm set strict-ssl=false
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it works fine with me but to make changes using this command you must run it in a super user session -->sudo npm set strict-ssl=false   thanks a lot dear

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS**. You are using SSL for security and then explicitly turning it off, so then why bother with SSL in the first place? You are opening yourself up to man in the middle attacks since your client can no longer be sure of the identity of the server.

Answer (score 2):

From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742#issuecomment-342501750), use the following environment variable:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/certfile.crt
```

After this, you can run any of the `npm` commands and nodejs will trust your extra certificate file.

The `.crt` file is a file that contains a prefix line, the base64 encoded cert and a suffix line.

If you don't have your root CA cert handy, you can generate the cert file from your URL, with the `openssl` command:

```
openssl s_client \
    -showcerts \
    -servername <host> \
    -connect <host>:443 2>/dev/null </dev/null | \
  openssl x509
```

Where `<host>` is the hostname of the url.  For example, using `google.com` for the host, the output looks something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIIIDCCBwigAwIBAgIQI/1aCHwDN94QFUhXJeIwODANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBU
(42 more lines)
E+Hv1bJSbOMSNCDzqRM3JUzvM6Y=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Save that as your `.crt` file and add its path to the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable and you're all set.

Answer (score -3):

when I was trying to install npm on Ubuntu 16 i got the same error.
The following command worked for me.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: This is bad because it doesn't use SSL. Similar to doing this: `npm set strict-ssl=false`. Don't do this unless you don't care about security at all.