# coinbase API issue

Tags: node.js, express, coinbase-api

I'm trying to connect to Coinbase API, using node v12.16.3 with:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
....
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var client = new Client({
    apiKey: 'my_apiKey',
    apiSecret: 'my_apiSecret'
  });
  client.getCurrencies(function(err, currencies) {
    console.log(' *************** Crypto Currencies *************** ');
    console.log(currencies);
    console.log(err);
  });
);
```

but unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1474:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:917:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:687:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
}
```

already tried to run :
`npm config set strict-ssl false` or `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
but it doesn't work. Could you help me? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs https request UNABLE\_TO\_GET\_ISSUER\_CERT\_LOCALLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651407/nodejs-https-request-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally)

Comment: and also try this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52007971/1848109

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have access to https://api.pro.coinbase.com and https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com

If not, your router/admin/provider may block this site in firewall and you don't have access to it. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60082096/2697300)

BTW. Package `coinbase` is deprecated, better use [`coinbase-pro-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinbase-pro-node)

Comment: I have access to the site to which the library is connecting (which is api.coinbase.com) and the coinbase-pro-node is not a superset of the other library; it is simply a new library that you can use only if you have a coinbase pro account