# Response as undefined after an API call

Tags: node.js, api, botframework

I am using the request library to fetch a response from an API, everything was working fine but as of recent, I have started to get local issuer certificate error from the API although the same code is working on my colleague's system.

I have already tried updating the node version and all the version changes regarding the request package of node

The exact error is:

> unable to get local issuer certificate node

[Here is the error snippet in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO6Sl.png)

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: Hi @ar_2412, Welcome to StackOverflow ! :) .  If your request does not get a response back -  then the statusCode will obviously be ```undefined```. That is the error you have attached in the screenshot, Can you show your code snippet or something to examine further.

Comment: @Charlie Sorry I can't share the code, but I have updated the error I am facing i.e. local issuer certificate error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs https request UNABLE\_TO\_GET\_ISSUER\_CERT\_LOCALLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651407/nodejs-https-request-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally)

Answer (score 0):

Could u please console only response..After that u can easily see that there is statusCode is available or not.
Or if u get the statusCode then check its defined or not.
Ex: if(res.statusCode)
console.log("print status code", this.res.statusCode);

Answer (score 0):

This is an SSL error and yo need to make sure that your server's certificate is valid.

With your claim that it used to work - but it stopped working recently with the SSL error message, the possibilities are that either your servers certificate is expired in between or the Sectigo AddTrust External CA Root Expiring May 30, 2020.

https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT

Updating the certificate is outside the scope of this answer. You may have to do it yourself or contact the admin.